# Python's paramiko with threading, strange delay

Tags: python, multithreading, paramiko

In order to check the existence of a certain file on many servers, I've created a threaded class that uses [`paramiko`](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/) to execute a remote command using ssh. The results of each thread are inserted into a thread safe [`Queue.Queue`](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html), and I read its contents after all the `join()`s are done. This is the main part of the thread:

```
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.connect(self.server, username='linqmap', timeout=5)
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('my_command')
```

This solution works great, but there is a strange behavior that got my attention. The thread logs its `__init__` time:

```python
def __init__(self, server, queue, lock):
    ...
    self.start_time=datetime.datetime.now()
    ...
```

And its finish time (the time where the results was inserted into the queue):

```python
def _report(self, message, status):
    duration=datetime.datetime.now()-self.start_time
    ...
    self.queue.put( (self.server, duration, message, status) )
```

The problem is that the duration is very similar for all the threads. For a small number (~5) of threads, it is about 3 seconds. For larger numbers (~100), it is about 30 seconds.

Since there is a timeout of 5 seconds in the connection, I presumed all the threads will either finish in 5 seconds or fail. Any idea what happened here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `timeout` is just for the TCP connect, not the entire operations on the connection.

I would expect the `__init__` to be called on the original thread - only the `run()` method runs on the new thread. So your time might be invalid.

SSH involved a certain amount of processing for the encryption and setup of the tunnel, so it may be worth looking at the CPU usage on the client, to see if that is your limiting factor for 100's of connections.

Comment: Thanks! Surprisingly, it was indeed a CPU load issue.. I will use a thread pool.